# strcmp not working in iterative server C

Tags: c, server

We are working on an iterative server in C, which can be used with the telnet client on UNIX. Our Code works fine, except when it comes to performing stringcompares using strcmp(). We have tried the fix using "\n" as suggested in this forum. The Code below works fine. We even enter the method `checkInput(in,out)`

```
while(read(fileDescriptor,in,2000)>0)
{
    in[strlen(in)-1]=0;
    checkInput(in,out);
    write(fileDescriptor,out,strlen(out));
}
```

When we enter `checkInput(in,out)` we want to campare the string the user enters via telnet with another predefined string. But we always end in the else statement even though the twor strings are exactly the same.

```
void checkInput(char in[],char out[])
{
    char tempString[]="GET TEMPERATURE\n";
    char buzzer[]="GET BUZZER";

    if(strcmp(in,tempString)==0)
    {
        strcpy(out,"Get Temp!");
        //sprintf(out,"%d",temp);
    }

    else if(strcmp(in,"GET HUMIDITY")==0)
    {
        strcpy(out,"Get Hum!");
        //sprintf(out,"%d",hum);
    }

    else if(strcmp(in,"GET LIGHT")==0)
    {
        strcpy(out,"Get Light!");
        //sprintf(out,"%d",light);
    }

    else if(strcmp(in,"GET LED")==0)
    {
        strcpy(out,"Get LED!");
        //sprintf(out,"%d",led);
    }

    else if(strcmp(in,"GET SOUND")==0)
    {
        strcpy(out,"Get Sound!");
        //sprintf(out,"%d",sound);
    }

    else if(strncmp(in,buzzer, 11)==0)
    {
        strcpy(out,"Get Buzzer!");
        //sprintf(out,"%d",buzzer);
    }

    else if(strcmp(in,"exit")==0)
    {
        strcpy(out,"Exiting... Get Out!");
        exit(2);
    }
    else
    {
        strcpy(out,"\nDAAAAAMN YOU SERVER!!!!!!!!!\n");
        sprintf(out,"%d",strcmp(in,buzzer));
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank You!

Comment: are your strings properly NULL-terminated?  This might also be a good time to learn to use a debugger and step through the code and inspect the variables.

Comment: There isn't enough info here really, I think Chrisitan's suggestion might be reasonable, you need to check if the strings are null terminated. I think the easiest way for you to see what the issue is is to either use a debugger or print your string to see its contents

Comment: Are you confusing `read` with `fgets`? The function `checkInput` shortens a string by `1` which is a poor way of getting rid of a trailing newline (which may not exist). And what happens when `strlen(in)` is `0`?

Comment: what if you used `strncmp` instead, and specified the length of the static string as the 3rd parameter?

Comment: the posted code does not compile..  amongst other things, what is the declaration of `in` and `out`?

Comment: what are you expecting this: `in[strlen(in)-1]=0;` to accomplish?  Are you trying to eliminate a possible trailing newline?  If so, then use: `in[ strspn( in, "\n" ) ] = '\0';

Comment: strongly suggest replacing the call to `read()` with a call to `fgets()`

Comment: regarding: `write(fileDescriptor,out,strlen(out));`  strongly suggest using `fprintf()` rather than `write()`

Comment: the function: `read()` does not NUL terminate the input.  I'm thinking that is the root of the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's try a little experiment.

In one session, we start up a netcat (`nc` process) which listens for a connection and dumps what it receives through hexdump (`hd`) so that we can see what telnet actually sends:

```
$ nc -l 8888|hd
```

In another session, we use telnet to send a little string:

```
$ telnet localhost 8888 <<<"Hello, world!"
```

Now, what do we see in the first terminal?

```
$ nc -l 8888|hd
00000000  48 65 6c 6c 6f 2c 20 77  6f 72 6c 64 21 0d 0a     |Hello, world!..|
0000000f
$
```

Telnet sends CRLF at the end of each line (assuming the line was originally terminated with a LF). So when you're splitting the received input into lines on the server side, you need to remove both the `\r` and the `\n`. (If, for whatever reason, the original line was terminated by a `\r` instead of a `\n`, what you will receive on the other end will normally be a line terminated by `\r\0`, although telnet has an option to send `\r\n` in this case as well.

Note that you should not assume that a single `read` call will return an entire line nor that it will return only a single line. The amount of data which is produced by a single `read` call is subject to so many environmental variations that no assumptions whatsoever should be made. At a minimum, you should find the end of the line by scanning for a `\r` and then dropping both the `\r` and the following `\n` or `\0`. If no line terminator is found, more data will have to be read. If the line terminator is followed by more data, then it will need to be processed in a subsequent step, instead of (or before) reading more input from the socket.

For a bit more information on this subject, see [RFC-1123](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1123) "Requirements for Internet Hosts" (which defines the telnet protocol in Chapter 3), and in particular section 3.3.1 "Telnet End-of-line Convention".

Comment: Worth noting there are 2 `nc` packages that behave a bit differently from one another on this point. The *openbsd_netcat* doesn't like the `-l and -p` options together. The other package is *gnu-netcat*, which it looks like you are using here. Either way, good way to explain it.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: Ok, I removed the `-p` since gnu netcat seems to work either way. (Actually the point of using netcat and telnet like that was to illustrate how to diagnose problems.)

Comment: I'm just trying to snatch the pebbles from your hand here. I thought that was a dynamite example, I just stumbled into the issues trying to make it work `:)` (you get extra points and points for being old if you recall where the metaphor comes from)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Using strncmp silved my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

the following proposed code snippet should fix your problem

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


// prototypes
void checkInput(char in[],char out[]);
void readWriteLoop( void );

void readWriteLoop();
{
    char in[2000];
    char out[2000];

    FILE * fp = NULL;

    fp = fopen( ..., "a+" ); // replace .... with the actual I/O device name
    if( !fp )
    {
        perror( "fopen failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fopen successful

    while( fgets( in, sizeof( in ), fp) )  
    { 
        in[ strspn( in, "\n" ) ] = '\0'; 
        checkInput( in, out );
        fprintf( fp, "%s\n", out );
    }

    fclose( fp );
}
```